# next, previous and up links

Tags: hyperref, pdf, navigation

This question must have been asked and answered before on this forum, but I can't find the discussion. Sorry.

I have a document that has a natural tree structure. So I want "next", "previous" and "up" links, and a clickable menu when there are downlinks.

What latex package(s) should be used? The most useful thing would be to point me to a simple example of such latex source.

Excuse the ignorance, but will all (or most) pdf readers be able to handle this, or should the latex source be converted into something else (html perhaps)?

I might decide to learn how to use vim in text-folding mode, but this wouldn't solve my problem as I want the material to be read by other people and they will not want to learn vim.

Comment: I haven't used it but I think that the [varioref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package does this.

Comment: The `hyperref` package allows you to put anchors and links to them.